# Get Text From a disabled JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have been using the function getText() to read user Input in MyJTextField Until I have noticed that this does Not Look Possible with Disabled JTextField.

```
JTextField jtx = new JTextField();
jtx.setText("TEST");
jtx.setEnabled(false);
String str = jtx.getText();
System.out.println(str);
```

This does not return Anything and I am begining to think that it is because of the Disabled JTextField. Is there a Way to get Text From a Disabled JTextField or Should I just:

```
jtx.setEditable(false);
```

I do not want to do this. I want the field to be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried to recreate this issue in a simple app containing the disabled textfield and nothing else?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As an aside, who put text in the field & disabled it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works as expected (prints TEST whether the text field is enabled or disabled) - are you running your code in the EDT?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JTextField jtx = new JTextField();
            jtx.setText("TEST");
            System.out.println("Before: " + jtx.getText());
            jtx.setEnabled(false);
            System.out.println("After: " + jtx.getText());
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely get the text from a disabled `JTextField` using exactly the code you specified. Search for the issue somewhere else.